# AngularJS : How to properly transclude child elements in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

Here's some code : [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ToI9ggLdx1vtF4UGmYO8)

I'm trying to create a directive that wraps its children in some boilerplate.  But if the children have `ng-if` controlling their appearance, the "transclusion" doesn't work. Well it sort of does, but as you can see the `ng-if` logic is not getting passed through correctly.

I'd like to know how to fix it, but also where (if anywhere) this is described in the Angular docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** is that Angular initially replaces `ngIf` with a comment that it uses to track where to place the conditional code.  It's easiest to see with an example.

Your HTML:

```
<div control-group>
  <label>Test</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="editing.name" />
  <span class="text-error" ng-if="editing.name.length != 3"> Name must be 3 characters </span>
</div>
```

Looks like this inside your transclude function's `cloned` variable (`transclude(function (cloned) {`):

```
<div control-group>
  <label>Test</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="editing.name" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
  <!-- ngIf: editing.name.length != 3 -->
</div>
```

So, the element with class `text-error` that you're filtering on (below) isn't in `cloned`.  Just the comment is there.

```
var inputsAndMessages = cloned.filter('input, button, select, .text-error');
```

Since you're only transcluding elements that match the above filter the `ngIf` comment is lost.

**The solution** is to filter for comments as well and add them in your append (so Angular maintains it's reference point to the `ngIf`).  One way to do that is to replace the above with this (using the fact that an html comment is node type 8)

```
var messages = cloned.filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8; }); //comments

var inputs = cloned.filter('input, button, select')

var inputsAndMessages = inputs.add(messages);
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqvGu0jMtTeK4BehB4K7?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, that works -- you've explained what is happening. I guess in the real code, since I don't know whether there will be an `ng-if` on a sub-element or not, I need to set the directive definition `terminal: true` and can `$compile` myself.  That way I can re-arrange the elements before any `ng-if` get's compiled and turned into a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the directive where to place child elements with the [`ng-transclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude) directive: ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cl267N6EBgAVBpdWFtV8?p=preview))

```
 template: "<div class='control-group' ng-transclude>" +
                 "<label class='control-label' for=''></label>" +
                 "<div class='controls'></div>" +
              "</div>",
```

From the docs:

> Directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of the nearest parent directive that uses transclusion.
>
> Any existing content of the element that this directive is placed on will be removed before the transcluded content is inserted.

I wasn't sure what exactly your intent was since you have the `input` and `label` both in the template and as children in the HTML.  You might want to place your `ng-transclude` elsewhere.

Comment: I can't use `ng-transclude` because I want to transclude my input child elements at different points in the template.  So I need to use the more flexible `translude` functions.  I should probably add this point to my question.