# Transferring attributes in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I guess I have to make the jump to directives.

I have a directive in my html:

```
<ev-filter placeholder='{{pp.srcListFilter}}'
          ng-model='data.srcFilter'/>
```

that I want to replace (using a template) with:

```
<div class='filterbox'>
      <input id='srcFilter' type='text' 
                   placeholder='{{pp.srcListFilter}}'
                   data-ng-model='data.srcFilter'>
</div>
```

What I can't seem to get my head around is how to "transfer" the attributes id, placeholder, ng-model, etc,... from the directive to the template.  The variable value swill be different for each use, so I might have:

```
<ev-filter placeholder='{{pp.srcListFilter}}'
          ng-model='data.srcFilter'/>
```

or

```
<ev-filter placeholder='{{pp.subjectListFilter}}'
          ng-model='data.subFilter'/>
```

i.e. the variable names are not hardcoded. All the example online seem to manage the variables using scope, but they assume the names are hardcoded (always the same).  I can't do that because I might have multiple instances on a single page/managed by a single controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly transclude child elements in custom directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617499/how-to-properly-transclude-child-elements-in-custom-directive)